# Convert From Query to Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I have the following query that is giving output as desired:

```
var get = (from pg in _uow.PermissionGroups.Query()
           join pr in _uow.Permissions.Query() on pg.PermissionGroupId equals pr.PermissionGroupId
           join role in _uow.Roles.Query() on pr.Roles.Select(s => s.RoleId).FirstOrDefault() equals role.RoleId
           where pg.PermissionGroupName == "Services" && role.RoleId == 1
           select new { PermissionName = pr.PermissionName, Permission = true })
           .ToList<dynamic>();
```

I want to do this in Lambda exression using `Join()` but I am running into all sorts of exceptions:

```
var get2 = _uow.PermissionGroups.Query()
    .Join(
        _uow.Permissions.Query(),
        pgs => pgs.PermissionGroupId,
        prs => prs.PermissionGroupId,
        (pg, pr) => new 
        { 
            Permissions = pg.Permissons, 
            Roles = pr.Roles 
        })
    .Join(
        _uow.Roles.Query(),
        rs => rs.Roles.Select(e => e.RoleId).FirstOrDefault(),
        role => role.RoleId,
        (p, r) => new
        {
            PermissionName = p.Permissions.Select(d => d.PermissionName),
            PermissionGroupName = p.Permissions.Select(s => s.PermissionGroup.PermissionGroupName),
            Role = r
        })
    .Where(w => w.PermissionGroupName.FirstOrDefault() == "Services" && w.Role.RoleId == 1)
    .Select(c => new { PermissionName = c.PermissionName.SingleOrDefault(), Permission = true })
    .ToList<dynamic>();
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: What you actually mean is that you want to use function syntax instead of query syntax.

Comment: I would suggest you not change your linq query from query syntax to fluent syntax, since that would decrease the readability of your code. There are cases that fluent syntax is more attractive than query syntax and vice versa. The Joins are better interpreted using the query syntax. However that's a personal opinion.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, I exactly mean that. ChristosPaisios Yes, I understand that but if I were to code in fluent syntax then I would increase the compactness of my code and also want to solve it for learning purposes.